# Pixel 1 no longer detected by Android Studio 2.3.3 after Oreo Update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-8.0-oreo, android-studio-2.3

Android Studio 2.3.3 does not detect my Pixel 1 device when attempting to generate a build

It did detect it on Noughat, but not now that I updated to Oreo

I made sure to update Android Studio and all the SDK stuff

This seems like an issue other developers might be having

What are the steps to troubleshoot or make it work?

Thnx

Comment: Try enabling debug mode again, see if that works otherwise file a ticket in the official Android forum.

Comment: I have a Pixel 1 with Android O running. I have been able to use it for debugging with Android Studio 2.3.3. Something might be off with your Android studio or device settings. Please try to enable - disable debugging mode on your device and restart `adb` and Android Studio on your dev machine.

Comment: can you try updating android studio 3.0?

Answer (score 4):

Try to switch your phone in Transfer files mode. It helps me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. 
The solution to the problem was restart the adb service with rights of sudo.

```
sudo adb kill-server 

sudo adb start-server
```

Аfter that the connection was established.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this'll help, but it's worth a shot.

1) You might have `adb` off. Go to Settings, Developer Options, ADB. Make sure that it's on. You also have to make the device trust your development computer.

2)There's also a new version of Android Studio, 3.0. Try updating and see if that works.

3) It might be your driver. Make sure you have `Google USB Driver` or any other drivers applicable for `adb`

P.S. Make sure your cable isn't broken.